# How can I deal with a SystemException?

Tags: warning-messages, list-manipulation, parallelization, error-trapping

I have a list of functions that are being evaluated, using `ParallelTable[]`, and continue to get the error message:

```
Parallel`Developer`QueueRun::hmm: Received unexpected result SystemException[MemoryAllocationFailure] from KernelObject[4,local].
```

from time to time. The functions are randomly generated, which is why I do not get the error message each time. Is there any way to just automatically discard the functions that cause the error, without having the entire program freeze up, like it is currently doing, when I run into this problem?

Comment: Wrapping in `MemoryConstrained[]` might help with the freeze-up issue.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau - Thanks! That sounds like what I was looking for - I will try and see how that works!

Comment: @DanielLichtblau - That works, thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped.